# Need to rebind keyboard on EarthSiege 2

Tags: earthsiege-2

I just got the game fully working, even the videos, and have minimal crashes.
My one gripe is you have to screw with the old-school style of controls.
Is there a file in ES2's directory you can change to rebind the keys, or am i just going to have to set up an AHK for this game?

Answer (score 2):

well, did digging the hard way and found it under the ES2_FLCS.M50 file.
just gonna leave this here for posterity's sake, hope this helps someone in the future

Comment: Dang I loved this game.  Thanks for sharing the solution!